# RegEx and multiline PO files

Tags: regex, multiline, po

I'm trying to create a regex in Notepad++, just a simple search&replace.

The lines are the following:

> msgid ""
>
> "        CONSUMPTION_PLAN_ERR|The Finished Good's BOM has been changed
>   since production was added.\n"
>
> "        To continue using this Job with the new BOM, please update
>   lots and expiries.\n"
>
> "        Previous Production Records will not be updated.\n"
>
> msgstr ""
>
> "        The Finished Good's BOM has been changed since production was
>   added.\n"
>
> "        To continue using this Job with the new BOM, please update
>   lots and expiries.\n"
>
> "        Previous Production Records will not be updated.\n"

I need to change the double quotation marks but only on the msgid part. These double quotation marks should be changed to less than < and greater than > symbols, so the result would be the following:

> msgid <>
>
> <        CONSUMPTION_PLAN_ERR|The Finished Good's BOM has been changed
>   since production was added.\n>
>
> <        To continue using this Job with the new BOM, please update
>   lots and expiries.\n>
>
> <        Previous Production Records will not be updated.\n>
>
> msgstr ""
>
> "        The Finished Good's BOM has been changed since production was
>   added.\n"
>
> "        To continue using this Job with the new BOM, please update
>   lots and expiries.\n"
>
> "        Previous Production Records will not be updated.\n"

I would need a regex pattern that matches multiline examples like the above, no matter how many lines need to be changed.

I used this pattern to search:

```
msgid ""\r\n("(.+?)"\r\n){1,}
```

And this pattern to replace:

```
msgid <>\r\n<\2>\r\n
```

Which works somewhat but not exactly what I wanted. It only copies the last line, but not the two above it. I am doing something wrong but don't know what it is.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex, but it is not simple and it won't be efficient. A more efficient solution is to write a parser, or use a more flexible programming language to use a combination of at least two regexps: one would extract the block, and the second would replace the quotes.

A single regex solution will look like

*Find What*: `(?s)(?:\G(?!^(?<=.))|^msgid)(?:(?!^msg(?:id|str))[^"])*?\K"((?:(?!^msg(?:id|str))[^"])*?)"`
*Replace With*: `<$1>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FhtaSp/1).

**Details**

- `(?s)` - same as *`.` matches newline* when ON
- `(?:\G(?!^(?<=.))|^msgid)` - start of a line (`^`) and then `msgid`, or (`|`) the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^(?<=.))`)
- `(?:(?!^msg(?:id|str))[^"])*?`
- `\K` - match reset operator, the match buffer gets cleared
- `"` - a `"`
- `((?:(?!^msg(?:id|str))[^"])*?)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `(?:(?!^msg(?:id|str))[^"])*?` - any 0 or more, but as few as possible, occurrences of any char other than `"`, that does not start a `msgid` or `msgstr` char sequences at the start of a line
- `"` - a `"`.

[image]

Comment: Done, sorry I'm new here.